# How to fix ExecuteNonQuery error

Tags: c#

An exception is thrown on `ExecuteNonQuery`, how can I fix it?

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO transaction(ID,item_name,quantity,price,T_date) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\KCdb.accdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", item.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_date", dt.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Try This: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_date", dt);`

Comment: Give details of what is the exception, there could be soooo many different reason why this would fail, without the details of the exception, we cannot help you out

Comment: i have added exception code but still it show exception on this line
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guiding you, we need the exception , because there will be different reasons of failure.
But as I can see in your code there are some casts in assigning value to parameters, when your parameter is of DateTime type you should pass a DateTime as its value not a string. SO I think you should change `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_date", dt.ToString());` to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@T_date", dt);`

Comment: changed that but still getting exception

Comment: `string item = nTCbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
int price = int.Parse(nTPrice.Text);
int quantity = int.Parse(nTQuantity.Text);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;`

catching data from combo box and text box

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Change `transaction` to `[transaction]` and see what happens